# How to multiply matrix by its transpose in tensor notation

Tags: matrices, tensors

I am afraid I am getting quite lost in this tensor notation. Suppose I have a matrix $M$ and its transpose $M^T$. In component tensor notation we can write $M$ as $M^i_{~~j}$ and the transpose $M^T$ as $M_j^{~~i}$. I seek to multiply these together:
$$M^TM \rightarrow M_j^{~~i}M^i_{~~k}$$
The problem with this is that now I have the index $i$ over which I sum over as a top index for both matrices but matrix multiplication must have one index up and the other down. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

In ordinary notation
\begin{align}
(MM)_{ij}&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nM_{ik}M_{kj}\,,\\
(M^\top M)_{ij}&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nM_{ki}M_{kj}\,.
\end{align}
In index notation these equations are
\begin{align}
{(MM)^i}_j&={M^i}_k{M^k}_j\,,\\
{(M^\top M)^i}_j&={M_k}^i{M^k}_j\,.
\end{align}